# Help with JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help with a Regex expression to valid an ID pattern which is 7 characters where the first position is Alpha (A-Z) and ignore case and last 6 is Numeric (0-9).

Example: X155230 or x155230

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to find your pattern, [RegExr](http://regexr.com?2u68u), you just have to put it into JavaScript.

The actual Regex `/^[a-zA-Z]\d{6}/i`

Comment: You should definitely put the pattern into your answer as external links go dead.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
/^[a-z]\d{6}$/i
```

Comment: @ridgerunner - They're the same thing.  I don't like the idea of "dumbing down" the `\d` and `/i` switch, however.  That's fine for explaining what this does, but people will never learn if everything is dumbed down.

Comment: @cwolves: Its not a matter of dumbing down. Its a matter of efficiency (a regex is typically faster without the `i` flag), and accuracy (the `\d` in many regex engines means more than 0-9, it can include extra unicode digits from other languages.) That said, these differences are likely insignificant in this example, and either expression will work just fine.

Comment: fair enough, except that `\d` in JavaScript at least ___only___ matches `0-9` and many browsers have no performance difference (though some do)

Answer (score 1):

You could at least do some basic research in the javascript documentation.  The pattern you need is

```
/^[A-Za-z]\d{6}$/
```

Answer (score -1):

It's quite simple:

```
/^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}$/i
```

Comment: @cwolves is completely correct, but I don't think that means this deserves a minus 1.

Comment: +1 to undo the -1: I don't either, it's just unnecessary, not harmful :)

Comment: @cwolves @Renesis I was waiting for the downvotes to start. Oh well, I can spare the 2 points for being explicit. Thanks for the vote of confidence.